# Ugly font after KDE installation

Tags: fonts, kde, font-rendering, fontconfig

You all know the nice default font that come with Ubuntu, right?
I just wanted to play a little bit with Kubuntu and installed the meta package

> kubuntu-desktop

Everything was fine, however the font is now ugly as hell.
Not only on KDE, but also on Gnome, Unity etc.

Example:
[image]

How can I get the default font config back?

Comment: Look also at http://askubuntu.com/questions/159085/web-fonts-became-ugly-after-installing-kde

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you have to to disable font hinting, either through GNOME/KDE settings or by putting the following in ~/.fonts.conf (create the file if it doesn't exist):

```
<match target="font">
  <edit name="hinting" mode="assign">
    <bool>false</bool>
  </edit>
</match>
```

This is configurable because some people prefer crispier look reminiscent of Windows XP.

Comment: I confirm that this solved the problem.

Comment: This is also working for me, please select it as the answer.

Comment: I don't like font hinting

Answer (score 5):

In your home folder, rename `.fonts.conf` to `.fonts.conf.bak` then log out. Log back in and the fonts in Firefox are good to go.