# Installed KDE4.8 on Ubuntu and it messed up browser's fonts

Tags: 11.10, fonts, kde4

I installed KDE 4.8 on my 11.10 system just to try it out but didn't like it and eventually un-istalled it. But now the browser's font (both Firefox & Chromium) are messed up badly.

How can I restore them back to defaults?

[image]

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38757/ugly-font-after-kde-installation - remove the .fonts.conf worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, that messed up my terminal font... I ended up making .fonts.conf look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
   <const>none</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
   <const>hintslight</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
</fontconfig>
```