# Web fonts became ugly after installing KDE

Tags: kubuntu, fonts

After installing **kde-standard** on my Ubuntu 12.04,web fonts(both Firefox and Chrome) turned to ugly both in Gnome and KDE desktops.How do I get back good looking web fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to edit /home/yourusername/.fonts.conf.

Chances are Hinting has been changed, and you need to change it back to hintslight.

Here's how mine looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
   <const>none</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
   <const>hintslight</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: Yes, this fixed it, but now Droid fonts look bad, but they looked ok at `hintingstyle=hintfull`. So, i have to choose - Droid fonts or Ubuntu fonts...

Comment: It think, it should be noted, that rgba=none is not very good idea in our time with LCD screens everywhere. Setting it to rgb or correspondingly to your's monitor geometry if its not rgb.