# Fonts messed up after installing Kubuntu desktop on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, kubuntu, fonts

I decided I wanted to try Kubuntu since I had some difficulties with the Unity desktop. I do not remember exactly the command(s) I run, but I think I used `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`. Now the fonts are messed up both in KDE Plasma Desktop and in Unity. Here is an example from a web mail page:

[image]

Here is how it should look like (and how it looked like before installing Kubuntu) :

[image]

Here is what I have tried:

- I tried to look for a file `~/.fonts.conf` and disable font hinting, see this answer:
  [Ugly font after KDE installation](https://askubuntu.com/a/46082/156688). I also tried the modifications suggested in this answer:
  [Web fonts became ugly after installing KDE](https://askubuntu.com/a/159110/156688)
- I tried run `sudo apt-get purge pango-graphite` suggested in this answer:
  [font-messed-up](https://askubuntu.com/a/303441/156688)

**Update:**

It seems the font problem depends on the browser also. I made this small test HTML script:

```
<html>
    <body style="font-family: Sans-Serif;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur laoreet eros tortor, quis sodales quam ullamcorper tincidunt. Nunc a dolor ac urna sollicitudin aliquam ut id sem. Integer in sem magna. Phasellus tincidunt, nunc nec mattis facilisis, metus risus ultrices leo, quis convallis lorem nulla nec ante. Proin consectetur, mauris nec iaculis gravida, risus mi blandit ante, a sollicitudin neque diam ut nisi. Praesent nec leo quis sem accumsan dignissim. Ut ornare consectetur scelerisque. Etiam vel dapibus est. Phasellus imperdiet ipsum ut commodo tincidunt. Quisque malesuada et ante eu rutrum. Nulla porttitor blandit dui at sollicitudin.
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that the font family is `Sans-Serif` (it seems like the problem is most pronounced when `font-family` is set to only `Sans-Serif`)

Result in Chromium browser:

[image]

The page looks much better in Firefox:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/339565/how-can-i-make-palatino-look-good-in-firefox) is useful.

Comment: So disappointed to see you don't have a solution. I'm in the same boat. It happened since I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04. I don't think immediately after the upgrade, but more recently.

Comment: @Swoogan Actually I solved the problems with the Chromium fonts here: [How does Chromium browser select its default sans serif font?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/509417/how-does-chromium-browser-select-its-default-sans-serif-font). Also: please click the link `This bug also affects me` in the LaunchPad bug tracker [Installing "kubuntu-desktop" to normal ubuntu ruins unity](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/1335446)..

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/509417/how-does-chromium-browser-select-its-default-sans-serif-font

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try Ubuntu Restricted Extras if you haven't already, It contains a few fonts and True-type, True-Type will make text much clearer fixing the text that looks like it was typed on a 1995 Compaq!

Answer (score 0):

Just install Tweak Tool and give it a try and shutdown hinting and others in the tweak tool so it that it looks cool:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

or you will find it in ubuntu software center