# How does Chromium browser select its default sans serif font?

Tags: 14.04, fonts, chromium

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and I got [problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507966/fonts-messed-up-after-installing-kubuntu-desktop-on-ubuntu-14-04) with the fonts after installing Kubuntu desktop. For example

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p style="font-family: Sans-Serif;">
&#032;&#033;&#034;&#035;&#036;&#037;&#038;&#039;&#040;&#041;&#042;&#043;&#044;&#045;&#046;&#047;&#048;&#049;&#050;&#051;&#052;&#053;&#054;&#055;&#056;&#057;&#058;&#059;&#060;&#061;&#062;&#063;&#064;&#065;&#066;&#067;&#068;&#069;&#070;&#071;&#072;&#073;&#074;&#075;&#076;&#077;&#078;&#079;&#080;&#081;&#082;&#083;&#084;&#085;&#086;&#087;&#088;&#089;&#090;&#091;&#092;&#093;&#094;&#095;&#096;&#097;&#098;&#099;&#100;&#101;&#102;&#103;&#104;&#105;&#106;&#107;&#108;&#109;&#110;&#111;&#112;&#113;&#114;&#115;&#116;&#117;&#118;&#119;&#120;&#121;&#122;&#123;&#124;&#125;&#126;&#127;&#128;&#129;&#130;&#131;&#132;&#133;&#134;&#135;&#136;&#137;&#138;&#139;&#140;&#141;&#142;&#143;&#144;&#145;&#146;&#147;&#148;&#149;&#150;&#151;&#152;&#153;&#154;&#155;&#156;&#157;&#158;&#159;&#160;&#161;&#162;&#163;&#164;&#165;&#166;&#167;&#168;&#169;&#170;&#171;&#172;&#173;&#174;&#175;&#176;&#177;&#178;&#179;&#180;&#181;&#182;&#183;&#184;&#185;&#186;&#187;&#188;&#189;&#190;&#191;&#192;&#193;&#194;&#195;&#196;&#197;&#198;&#199;&#200;&#201;&#202;&#203;&#204;&#205;&#206;&#207;&#208;&#209;&#210;&#211;&#212;&#213;&#214;&#215;&#216;&#217;&#218;&#219;&#220;&#221;&#222;&#223;&#224;&#225;&#226;&#227;&#228;&#229;&#230;&#231;&#232;&#233;&#234;&#235;&#236;&#237;&#238;&#239;&#240;&#241;&#242;&#243;&#244;&#245;&#246;&#247;&#248;&#249;&#250;&#251;&#252;&#253;&#254;&#255;
</p>
        <p style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans';">
&#032;&#033;&#034;&#035;&#036;&#037;&#038;&#039;&#040;&#041;&#042;&#043;&#044;&#045;&#046;&#047;&#048;&#049;&#050;&#051;&#052;&#053;&#054;&#055;&#056;&#057;&#058;&#059;&#060;&#061;&#062;&#063;&#064;&#065;&#066;&#067;&#068;&#069;&#070;&#071;&#072;&#073;&#074;&#075;&#076;&#077;&#078;&#079;&#080;&#081;&#082;&#083;&#084;&#085;&#086;&#087;&#088;&#089;&#090;&#091;&#092;&#093;&#094;&#095;&#096;&#097;&#098;&#099;&#100;&#101;&#102;&#103;&#104;&#105;&#106;&#107;&#108;&#109;&#110;&#111;&#112;&#113;&#114;&#115;&#116;&#117;&#118;&#119;&#120;&#121;&#122;&#123;&#124;&#125;&#126;&#127;&#128;&#129;&#130;&#131;&#132;&#133;&#134;&#135;&#136;&#137;&#138;&#139;&#140;&#141;&#142;&#143;&#144;&#145;&#146;&#147;&#148;&#149;&#150;&#151;&#152;&#153;&#154;&#155;&#156;&#157;&#158;&#159;&#160;&#161;&#162;&#163;&#164;&#165;&#166;&#167;&#168;&#169;&#170;&#171;&#172;&#173;&#174;&#175;&#176;&#177;&#178;&#179;&#180;&#181;&#182;&#183;&#184;&#185;&#186;&#187;&#188;&#189;&#190;&#191;&#192;&#193;&#194;&#195;&#196;&#197;&#198;&#199;&#200;&#201;&#202;&#203;&#204;&#205;&#206;&#207;&#208;&#209;&#210;&#211;&#212;&#213;&#214;&#215;&#216;&#217;&#218;&#219;&#220;&#221;&#222;&#223;&#224;&#225;&#226;&#227;&#228;&#229;&#230;&#231;&#232;&#233;&#234;&#235;&#236;&#237;&#238;&#239;&#240;&#241;&#242;&#243;&#244;&#245;&#246;&#247;&#248;&#249;&#250;&#251;&#252;&#253;&#254;&#255;
</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

gives the following screenshot in Chromium browser:

[image]

whereas in Firefox, I get:

[image]

It seems like Chromium browser chooses some other font than `DejaVu Sans` as the default `Sans-Serif` font. I wonder why, and how to make it choose `DejaVu Sans` instead.

Also:

```
$ fc-match sans-serif
```

gives:

```
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
```

Comment: Open up Developer Tools and switch to the Computed tab on the right side. For me, a font of `sans-serif` gives 216 glyphs rendered in Arial and 7 glyphs rendered in DejaVu Sans.

Comment: @saiarcot895 Thanks, I think I found the problem.. It seems like all the default font settings in Chromium got reset when installing Kubuntu desktop. In `Settings->Web Content->Customize fonts..` all fonts was set to `Abyssinica SIL`..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found the problem.. It seems like all the default font settings in Chromium got reset when installing Kubuntu desktop. In Settings->Web Content->Customize fonts.. all fonts was set to `Abyssinica SIL`..

The fonts quality improved by selecting `DejaVu` font instead:

[image]

Example after changing:

[image]

Still, the quality could be improved by installing `Microsoft TrueType core fonts`:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

And then changing the default font settings again to `Times New Roman` and `Arial`:

[image]

Example of same page after final change:

[image]