# Restore fonts in 12.10

Tags: fonts

Before 12.10 I was used to restore fonts just by deleting the `~/fonts.conf` file and `~/fontconfig` folder.

I cannot locate those two files anymore in 12.10 and deleting `~/.cache/fontconfig/` doesn't help.

I have ugly fonts on chrome after installing `kubuntu-desktop`.
How can I restore the fonts?

Comment: So, suggestions in [Ugly font after KDE installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38757/ugly-font-after-kde-installation) are not helping? Did you log out and log back in?

Comment: @gertvdijk no, manually creating the `~/.fonts` file with the suggested content didn't help (it had effect on fonts, but that was even uglier).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem was not related to the KDE installation, but to the msfonts.

I removed the `mscorefonts`, logout and I got my fonts reverted to the original ones.

```
sudo apt-get purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```